# Why this() is not allowed in void method?

Tags: java, constructor, this

I’m creating class A with public void A() method that has this() as a first statement. A() method is obviously  not a constructor, but compiler complains about this() not being a first statement of some constructor which, I believe, is implicitly  created with super() as a first statement. What constructor and what this() statement does the compiler refer to? Thank you.

```
class A
{
    public void A(){this();}
}
```

Output 
    error: call to this must be first statement in constructor
        public void A(){this();}
                            ^
    1 error

Comment: Because `this()` is only allowed as the first statement in a constructor, and a `void` **function** isn't a constructor. You need `public A() {}` - using `this()` there would be infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

`super()` refers to the constructor of the parent class and this() refers to the constructor of the subclass.  You cannot use `this()` anywhere except in a constructor of a different signature and only as the first statement.For example this is valid.

```
          A(int x){
              this(); // Calling a no argument constructor of the same class
          }
```

But this is invalid , it throws a compilation error because this is recursive construuctor invocation.

```
          A(){
             this();
          }
```

You cannot use `this()` in methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It is just confusing that the compiler refers to the public void A() method as a constructor. The error message doesn’t reflect the real problem I assume.

Comment: You are correct.  That could be reported as a compiler bug :-)